# C# Parallel.Invoke : the operation was canceled Exception?

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0

*Hi ,*

the following code is working fine but sometimes I got **the operation was canceled exception** ?

```
 var _options = new ParallelOptions();
    _options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5;
    Parallel.Invoke(_options, 
        () =>
            {
                //get list of item1 
                foreach (var item in lst_item1)
                {
                    // do some logic here
                }
            },
        () =>
        {
            //get list of item1 
            foreach (var item in lst_item2)
            {
                // do some logic here
            }
        },
          () =>
          {
        //get list of item1 
        foreach (var item in lst_item2)
        {
           // do some logic here
        }
    });
// continue logic code
```

*Any help would be greatly appreciated!*

*Regards,*

Comment: some how in your logic .. `_options.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested`  getting `true`..

Comment: thanks Moumit for the quick response, I will check the code  but  how to avoid/handle this situation ?

Comment: Did you find what was wrong Reda?

Comment: Hi Kalyan,The code is fine, It was a bug in an internal libraries.